# Pages keep display error "You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I want my login page just one field, but there is an error displayed on my index.php
This is my index.php page:

```
<?php include('supsrwk_epenyenggaraan.php'); ?>
<?php

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6)`{
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}
$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);
 switch ($theType) `{case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";break;   case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;} return $theValue;
}`}`
$colname_maklumatkuarter = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['No_KP']))
 $colname_maklumatkuarter = $_SESSION['No_KP'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_supsrwk_epenyenggaraan, $supsrwk_epenyenggaraan);
$query_maklumatkuarter = sprintf("SELECT * FROM maklumatkuarter WHERE No_KP = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_maklumatkuarter, "text"));
$maklumatkuarter = mysql_query($query_maklumatkuarter, $supsrwk_epenyenggaraan) or die(mysql_error());
$row_maklumatkuarter = mysql_fetch_assoc($maklumatkuarter);
$totalRows_maklumatkuarter = mysql_num_rows($maklumatkuarter);$colname_maklumatkuarter = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['No_KP']))`{`
$colname_maklumatkuarter = $_SESSION['No_KP'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_supsrwk_epenyenggaraan, $supsrwk_epenyenggaraan);
$query_maklumatkuarter = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `maklumatkuarter` WHERE No_KP = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_maklumatkuarter, "text"));
$maklumatkuarter = mysql_query($query_maklumatkuarter, $supsrwk_epenyenggaraan) or die(mysql_error());
$row_maklumatkuarter = mysql_fetch_assoc($maklumatkuarter);
$totalRows_maklumatkuarter = mysql_num_rows($maklumatkuarter);
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}
if (isset($_POST['No_KP'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['No_KP'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "/supsrwk_epenyenggaraan/aduan.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "/supsrwk_epenyenggaraan/index.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_supsrwk_epenyenggaraan, $supsrwk_epenyenggaraan);
  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT No_KP, FROM maklumatkuarter WHERE No_KP=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text")); 
  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $supsrwk_epenyenggaraan) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";
    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       
    if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SELAMAT DATANG KE SISTEM e-Penyenggaraan</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>">
               <div align="center">
                  <input name="No_KP" type="text" class="txtbox" placeholder="NO KAD PENGENALAN" required>
              <div align="center">
                  <button class="loginbtn">LOG MASUK</button>
        <button class="loginbtn" type="reset">SEMULA</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the error appeared on my index.php page is You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM maklumatkuarter WHERE No_KP='960925135408'' at line 1.

I hope someone can help me solve this problem. I am just a beginner in coding.Thanks a lot

Comment: `%s` is what ?...

Comment: i am using dreamweaver

Comment: %s what is this @mirr

Comment: syntax of string declaration right?i dont know too coz im using dreamweaver and that %s automatically writen when i insert "user log in" from the menu provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT No_KP, FROM maklumatkuarter WHERE No_KP=%s
```

I guess the error is in the ',' try remove it. It's the third query

Do it like this:

```
 "SELECT No_KP FROM maklumatkuarter WHERE No_KP=%s
```